# Where do you get Example/Sample Databases from?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I'm looking for some example or sample databases (sales / production / employee / sports / Etc) to test my skills on other systems. So far my skills are limited to one sector education and i want to branch out see if the skill I've learned can be applied easily to other markets.

Ideally they would be large data sets. I can't seem to find any myself that are free or of any use. Format isn't much of an issue as i have used most forms of SQL, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, there are sample databases used (frequently in examples) and they are to be found here (rather confusingly) in the "documentation" section, under "other docs" - [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html). I'm afraid that I can't help with SQL Server, but I'm sure that there are others here who can.

- Example Databases Title  Download DB HTML Setup Guide    PDF Setup Guide
- [employee data](https://launchpad.net/test-db/) (large dataset, includes data and test/verification suite)      Launchpad
- [world](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world.sql.gz) database
- [sakila](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.zip) database
- [menagerie](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/menagerie-db.zip) database

You might also want to check out my reply [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105534/34007) to a poster who was looking for NoSQL datasets (shouldn't make a difference whether it's NoSQL or not).

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, here are a few options that may be useful:

- The [Contoso BI Retail database](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18279) is freely available. Niko Neugebauer makes heavy use of it in his [Columnstore blog series](http://www.nikoport.com/columnstore/), and it seems to work well for that purpose.
- Microsoft provides an [AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550) database, and Adam Machanic has [instructions for expanding it into a larger data set](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/10/17/thinking-big-adventure.aspx).
- Brent Ozar made a copy of the [Stack Overflow database](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/) available on BitTorrent. (If you can't use BitTorrent, you can also load it yourself following [these instructions](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/querying-the-stackoverflow-data-dump/). It's a little bit of a pain the latter way, but it does work and it's an interesting data set.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Transaction Processing Performance Council](http://tpc.org) publishes free of charge all its [current benchmark documentation](http://www.tpc.org/information/current_specifications.asp), which includes database schemas and tools to populate them. They are designed to be database-agnostic, so you can deploy them on pretty much any database platform.