# Databases for training (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump

I'm practicing for enrich my knowledge, and i would like to have more databases than actually i have (2).

Where i can found free databases for practice? If it's possible, big databases.

I'm traing to looking for some kind of comunity where people upload their databases for practice, If exist.

Comment: Take a look at my answere [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118493/34007). You can also try [hammerdb](http://www.hammerdb.com/) - I think that it can generate arbitrary sized databases. You could also look at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets) - they use these datasets for Masters projects in University!

Comment: [Sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a wikipedia database you can download from the following link:

- [Wikipedia:Database download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download)

> Wikipedia offers free copies of all available content to interested users. These databases can be used for mirroring, personal use, informal backups, offline use or database queries (such as for Wikipedia:Maintenance). All text content is multi-licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License (CC-BY-SA) and the GNU Free Documentation License (GFDL). Images and other files are available under different terms, as detailed on their description pages. For our advice about complying with these licenses, see Wikipedia:Copyrights.